# Is this condition for the intersection of two lines strict?

Tags: vectors

From page 20 of the book "Vectors, Tensors, and the Basic Equations of Fluid Mechanics: Cartesian Vectors and Tensors: Their Algebra §2.35":

> Exercise 2.35.4. Show that the two lines  $\vec x=\vec a+ s\vec{l}$,
> $\vec x = \vec b + s\vec{m}$,  where $s$ is a parameter and  $\vec l$
> and $\vec m$ are two unit vectors, will intersect if $\vec a\cdot(\vec l\times\vec m)=\vec b\cdot(\vec l\times \vec m),$ and find their point
> of intersection.

Isn't it obvious that the above condition is satisfied if $\vec l$ is parallel to $\vec m,$ or am I not getting something?

Comment: In which dimension are we? 3? With $\cdot$ you mean the scalar product and with $\times$ the cross product?

Comment: Yes, you are all right. In a book with such contents, its exercise should cover at least 3 dimensions and that the dot and cross are traditional scalar and cross products, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Indeed, $$\vec l\parallel \vec m\implies \vec l\times \vec
       m=\vec0\implies \vec a\cdot(\vec l\times\vec m)=\vec b\cdot(\vec
       l\times \vec m);$$ so, you're absolutely right that the given
   condition $$\vec a\cdot(\vec l\times\vec m)=\vec b\cdot(\vec l\times
   \vec m)\tag1$$ is insufficient for the lines $\vec x=\vec a+
   s\vec{l}$ and $\vec x = \vec b + s\vec{m}$ (where $\vec l$ and $\vec
   m$ are unit vectors) to intersect: we also require that the two
   lines are non-parallel, i.e., $$\forall k\in\mathbb R\quad\vec l\neq
   k\vec m.\tag2$$
2. In fact, these two conditons together are ***equivalent*** to the
   intersection of the two lines, since the distance between two
   non-parallel (i.e., skew or intersecting) lines is given by (where
   the symbols have their usual meanings)
   $$\left|\vec{AB}\cdot\hat{\vec{n}}\right|.$$